# Permutations and combinations ! 9 different fruit pies divided between three

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Different fruit pies are divided between 3 people so that each person gets and odd number of pies. Find the number of ways this can be done??
hint- so many combinations are added to get this answer ..

Comment: Are the pies distinguishable, or do we care only how many pies each person gets?

Comment: yep they are distinguishable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it by splitting into cases: $7$-$1$-$1$, $5$-$3$-$1$, $3$-$3$-$3$.

First case: The lucky person who gets $7$ pies can be chosen in $\binom{3}{1}$ ways. Her pies can be chosen in $\binom{9}{7}$ ways. For each choice, the older of the unlucky people can be assigned her pie in $\binom{2}{1}$ ways, for a total of $\binom{3}{1}\binom{9}{7}\binom{2}{1}$.

Next two cases: it's your turn. Then add up.

Comment: but in the answer ,they multiply the so stated value with 3C1..do you know why???

Comment: In my calculation for the $7$-$1$-$1$ there is a $\binom{3}{1}$, which is explained. There will be a similar $\binom{3}{1}$ in the $5$-$3$-$1$, though it may masquerade as part of a $3!$. For the $3$-$3$-$3$ there won't be, one natural expression for that one is $\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}$.

Comment: okay would please elaborate on your statement v\The lucky person who gets 7 pies can be chosen in 3C1 ways.

Comment: There are $3$ people. One of them will get $7$ pies. Who it will be can be chosen in $\binom{3}{1}$ ways.

Comment: Thank you soo much..Done and got the answer

Comment: One last question : would you plz explain this too "There will be a similar 3C1 in the 5-3-1, though it may masquerade as part of a 3!."

Comment: Can choose who gets $5$ in $\binom{3}{1}$ ways. Which ones she gets can be chosen in $\binom{9}{5}$ ways. The person who gets $3$ can then be chosen in $\binom{2}{1}$ ways. Her pies can be chosen in $\binom{4}{3}$ ways. Or else choose $5$ pies, then choose $3$. This can be done in $\binom{9}{5}\binom{4}{3}$ ways. We have $3$ "bundles" of pies. They can be distributed in $3!$ ways.